# How to nack a message when using a google cloud function tiggered by pub / sub

Tags: google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-pubsub

Can any one can tell me how to nack a cloud function triggered by a pub/sub topic (in order to be redelivered later)?
Thanks

Comment: Crash and you nack!

Comment: Sorry Guillaume, but that is not what i observe.
When i crash (using a "raise RuntimeError") for instance => The function is never called back again (Note that i didn't select the option to "Retry in case off error" on the function definition). I counted on PUB/SUB NACK for the function to be calledAgain.

Comment: If i use an subscription push to an HTTP function and return something else that "20x" HTTP Code => That is ok => The function is called again, but using the Pub/Sub topic trigger and crashing, the behaviour seem different....

Comment: I missed a part in my comment, the current answer repeat what I said BUT you need to tick the check box!!

Answer (score 1):

If you want messages to be retried, then you need to select the "Retry on failure" option. See the details for this option in the [Cloud Console Function creation](https://console.cloud.google.com/functions/add):

[image: retry]

Without this option set, Cloud Functions will acknowledge the message regardless of the result of executing your code, meaning the message will not be redelivered. With this option set, if you raise an exception in your code, then the message should be redelivered and your function executed again.

Comment: Thanks for all of you.Seems clear to me but this system looks a bit poor compared to the retry and DLQ options that exist for push subscriptions on http endpoints.